# Функция getdate() в формате "Июнь" sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Я совсем новичок в sql.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли сделать так чтобы удаляло все даты больше текущего месяца и меньше определенной даты? Все месяца в формате слов "Июнь". Моя конструкция явно неверна:

```
delete from www where [Источник]='База' 
and ([год]<=2017) or ([год]=2018 and [месяц] <= DATENAME(month, GETDATE()))
```

Изначально было так:

```
delete from www 
where [Источник]='База' 
and ([год]=2016 and [месяц] not in ('Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь')) 
or ([год]=2017 and [месяц] not in ('Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь')) 
or ([год]=2018 and [месяц] not in ('Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь')
```

Правильное решение(был выбран другой столбец для сравнения):

```
 delete from www
 where [Источник]='База'
 and ([Дата] < CONVERT(datetime, '2016-05-01')
 or [Дата] > eomonth(getdate()))
```

Comment: И что значит *все даты больше текущего месяца*, в приведенном вами примере, вы как раз пытаетесь удалить все даты меньше текущего месяца. Дополните, пожалуйста ваш вопрос схемой таблицы.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server MS

Comment: Вы правы, мне нужно удалить всё, кроме всех месяцев с начала текущего года

Comment: Нужно автоматизировать, чтобы не добавлять месяц каждый раз, желательно и год, но это не сейчас.

Comment: Прикрепите схему таблицы и перенесите ваш код в вопрос, путем редактирования.

Comment: с такой моделью данных ваш еще ждет много неприятных сюрпризов и ненужных сложностей. Вместо двух полей заведите одно поле `[дата]` и сравнивайте даты с датами.

Comment: @Андрей какие у вас еще есть столбцы в таблице? Мб есть полная дата?

Comment: Есть Дата в формате 2018-11-01, можно её задействовать?

Comment: @Андрей, если у этого поля [правильный тип данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#DateandTimeDataTypes) то можете просто сравнивать это поле с `CONVERT(datetime, '2018-07-01')`

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов решения вашей проблемы несколько:

**Первый**, просто удалять все то что меньше текущей даты за вычетом месяца, решается так:

```
DELETE FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [FullDate] < cast(dateadd(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()) as date)
```

На выходе имеем данные (сегодня 23.11.2018) с 23.10.2018 по 24.11.2018.

**Второй**, удалять все то, где дата меньше чем первое число текущего месяца:

```
DELETE FROM #MyTable
WHERE [FullDate] < cast(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month,0, GETDATE()),0) as date)
```

На выходе имеем данные только за текущий месяц.

---

*Где [MyTable] - наименование таблицы, [FullDate] - наименование поля в котором у вас хранится дата в представлении 2018-11-01.*